# Running external script gets stuck when input is too large

Tags: miktex, input

I'm using the `\input{|perl script.pl}` command to run an external perl script. I have enabled the options `-enable-pipes` and `-enable-write18`. This worked fine for several years, but stopped working recently. While build with pdflatex the build just gets stuck with 0% CPU usage and a perl process in the task manager, also with 0% CPU usage. This occured after updating my MiKTeX installation, but I also haven't used TeX in a while so I'm not entirely sure if it was caused by the update.

I've experimented with the script because "small" perl scripts still work. The problem occurs when the input from the script exceeds ~4KB. Is there a buffer size that I can increase to make this work?

Minimal example:

input_test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{|perl test.pl}
\end{document}
```

test.pl

```
my @i = (1..257); # 1..256 works
for (@i){
    print("0123456789ABCDEF");
}
```

Used MiKTeX version:

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.0.1 (MiKTeX 20.10)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with jpeg version 9.3
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.1; using 4.1
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Comment: This seems to be problem with MiKTeX 20.10. I've tried the older 20.6 version which still works.

Comment: that is the wrong place to report such a problem. Go the miktex github tracker and open an issue.

Comment: Did that just now. At first I wasn't sure if this really is a bug.